# SystemUtil.Run not working in vb script

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I opened a notepad and typed this command :
 `SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome"`
and saved the file with `.vbs` extension. When I run it, it throws a `Object Required : SystemUtil` error. But the same thing runs in `QTP`. Why is that?

Comment: No `SystemUtil` object in VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript has just 2 builtin objects that can be called directly `WScript` and `Debug`. As alternative to `SystemUtil.Run` you may use [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: u mean to say that vb script interpreter will not be able to recognize such objects? If so, is there any add in to vb script that can make it recognize Systemutil.Run object?

Comment: Yes, as for example ASP has `Server` and `Response` which are part of it own object model environment. I never heard about any WSH add in.

Answer (score 6):

`SystemUtil` is part of QTP and can be used in QTP tests but not in stand-alone VBScript.

Comment: u mean to say that vb script interpreter will not be able to recognize such objects? If so, is there any add in to vb script that can make it recognize Systemutil.Run object

Comment: @Ashwin the VBScript interpreter isn't able to recognize `SystemUtil` since it doesn't exist in a regular VBScript script. The `SystemUtil` object is created and added to the script by QTP, just like you can't do `Browser("title:=.*")` in a regular VBScript, such constructs are only available in QTP tests.

Comment: so does qtp have its own version of vb script interpreter? ca that version be used for interpreting scripts written in notepad?

Comment: @Ashwin no, you cannot use qtp syntax outside qtp